# Powerful numbers in Pell solutions (or, more generally, any Lucas sequence)

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

There are several definitive results regarding perfect powers in the Pell numbers — *e.g.*, the only perfect power is $P_7=169=13^2$.

On the other hand, when it comes to [powerful numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number), I've only found “non-effective” results [sorry, I don't know a better word for it!], such as those by Ribenboim and Yabuta‘s [that the ABC conjecture implies that there are finitely many powerful numbers in each Lucas sequence](http://www.emis.de/journals/RCM/Articulos/905.pdf).

Are there any results which are more definitive, *e.g.* “if $d$ has property X, then $v$ in $u^2-dv^2=1$ is powerful if and only if Y”?